# Django creating dynamic model on Run-time, need to restart the server to reflect it, why?

Tags: django, dynamic, models

I'm creating dynamic models by referring this link https://code.djangoproject.com/wiki/DynamicModels, from this I'm able to create Table to the Database on runtime.

And can see the created table by below command

```
python manage.py inspectdb test1
```

it returns in django models.py format,

By next step i'm trying to take this created Table to the app's models.py file by below command

```
python manage.py inspectdb test1 > app/models.py
```

Then the mdoels.py I get some thing like this

```
class Test1(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_lengtgh=255)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_lengtgh=255)
```

Then I'm rendering this models into forms.py

```
from models import Test1

class Test1Form(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Test1
```

and then calling this form to views.py and rendering it to template as input form.

***views.py***

```
from forms import Test1Form

def myveiw(request, template_name="mytemplate.html"):
    args = {}
    form = Test1Form()
    args['form'] = form
    return TemplateResponse(request, template_name, args)
```

***mytemplate.html***

```
<form method="post">{% csrf_token %}
    {{form}}
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Here every thing is working fine on runtime, but each and every time I need to restart the django server to see the form in the template, why? Atfter Restarting I can see the form in the template.

Why it needs a restart, can you guys please help me for this, is my way is correct or need to change my approach? Please let me know it will be very great full for me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: where is your view function?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem, I had to run `makemigrations` and `migrate` commands after creating the dynamic models to fix it. Try adding the following script right after creating your models:

```
from django.core.urlresolvers import clear_url_caches
from django.utils.module_loading import import_module
from django.core.management import call_command

admin.site.register(model, admin_opts)
reload(import_module(settings.ROOT_URLCONF))
clear_url_caches()

call_command('makemigrations')
call_command('migrate')
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Let me work out on this and revert you back.

Comment: @AjayKumar any luck?